# How to unit test a function which only changes internal state

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

Assume the following class

```
class Observable() {
    constructor() { this._cbs = []; }

    on(cb) {
        this._cbs.push(cb);
    }

    off(cb) {
         this._cbs.splice(this._cbs.indexOf(cb));
    }

    trigger() {
        this._cbs.forEach((cb) => cb());
    }
}
```

How should I unit test the `on` method. Now I could inspect the `this._cbs` array and simply verify that the callback is pushed onto it. But if I do that I apply implementation knowledge to my tests. Or I could spyOn the callback and call `trigger` and check if the callback is called or not. However, this is not an integration test.

So in general, what would be the approach to unit test function which only have internal effects ?

Comment: If your class under test changes the observable state of the system (some property in your case) then you can assert on the changes happened.

Comment: what about putting a spy?

Comment: The only operation in the `on` method is using the `Array.prototype.push` function which is a part of the JavaScript language. You don't need to test that `push` will function correctly because it is part of the language. The only thing you can check is the result which is what you mentioned.

Comment: Note that the example I give is a very basic one. Of course in real apps the function can be very complex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that if your method only changes internal state, the only way to verify that would be through publicly accessible methods (e.g. if your class had a `.count()` function you could check that afterwards.)

Without an external mechanism to verify the internal operation it's very hard to check.

Sometimes in C# if this was really important logic, I'd use the `[InternalsVisibleTo]` attribute to check (in you case `_cbs`) the internal state of the class.

Alternatively if this was not very important functionality it may be sufficient  to know that a function was called. So in that example you might provide a mocked `_cbs` as a parameter and check that `.push()` was called.

Answer (score 1):

In this case your [aggregate](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/DDD_Aggregate.html) is the class `Observable`, which has an [invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_(computer_science)) called `_cbs`. Now the only business value that you could test your [System Under Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_under_test) against is the business logic that accesses the invariant -that changes the state of the observable system-, that is to assert the outcome of the flow of the called business logic.